# Update an xml file in a storage folder by adding nodes using C#

Tags: c#, xml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm making a universal app in C# and I'm trying to update an xml file in the storage folder by adding some nodes to it. Ideally, starting with a file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyRoot>
<ParentNode>
<myNode1>value1</myNode1>
<myNode2>value2</myNode2>
</ParentNode>
</MyRoot>
```

I would like to add other nodes in order to obtain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyRoot>
<ParentNode>
<myNode1>value1</myNode1>
<myNode2>value2</myNode2>
</ParentNode>
<ParentNode>
<myNode1>value3</myNode1>
<myNode2>value4</myNode2>
</ParentNode>
</MyRoot>
```

What I obtain instead is an invalid xml file with the content I want appended to the previous content like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyRoot>
<ParentNode>
<myNode1>value1</myNode1>
<myNode2>value2</myNode2>
</ParentNode>
</MyRoot><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyRoot>
  <ParentNode>
    <myNode1>value1</myNode1>
    <myNode2>value2</myNode2>
  </ParentNode>
  <ParentNode>
    <myNode1>value3</myNode1>
    <myNode2>value4</myNode2>
  </ParentNode>
</MyRoot>
```

Here is the code

```
StorageFile myFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myFile.xml");
using (IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await myFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    // convert IRandomAccessStream to IO.Stream
    Stream s = writeStream.AsStreamForWrite();

    //xml
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(s);
    document.Root.Add(
        new XElement("ParentNode",
        new XElement("myNode1", "value3"),
        new XElement("myNode2", "value4"))
        );
    document.Save(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your call to `XDocument.Load` you are positioned at the end of the stream, so the call to `document.Save` will append the new contents at the end of the stream.

As long as you're only adding nodes to the existing XML making the file longer with every save, you could resolve the issue by moving to the beginning of the stream, before calling `document.Save`:

```
document.Root.Add(
    new XElement("ParentNode",
    new XElement("myNode1", "value3"),
    new XElement("myNode2", "value4"))
    );
s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // <-- add this line
document.Save(s);
```

If you start removing nodes, this won't work because not all of the old file will be overwritten and some remains will stay at the end. In this case you will need to close the stream after loading it and create a new file for saving by overwriting the existing one:

```
StorageFile newFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("myFile.xml",
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very helpful because it includes also the "removing nodes" scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("yourfile.xml");

        var root = doc.DocumentElement;

        var parentNode = doc.CreateElement("ParentNode");
        root.AppendChild(parentNode);

        var myNode1 = doc.CreateElement("myNode1");
        myNode1.Value = "value3";
        parentNode.AppendChild(myNode1);

        // ...add more nodes etc...

        doc.Save("yourfile.xml");
```

Comment: I was using xmlDocument before but I had the same problem, furthermore  I find XDocument easier and cleaner.